# Display a multi dimensional list in Flask HTML

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Consider I have the below multi-dimensional list which I would like to display in Flask HTML Page.

**Sample List**

```
list_html = [['Mun--CEO--Bank', 'Chee--CEO--Trust'], ['Miloš--Researcher--College'], ['Mun--CEO--Bank']]
```

I am trying to display this list in Flask Webpage. Where each item in list is displayed in the next line (please refer the expected output)

**Sample Code**

```
{% for dat in list_html %}
    <div><span></span><ul><li> {{data[dat]}} </li></ul></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Here, the **data** refers to the list_html which I pass it in render_template.

I am unable to display each item as a new line in the output HTML page.

**Expected Output**

```
* Mun--CEO--Bank
* Chee-CEO-Trust

* Miloš--Researcher--College

* Mun--CEO--Bank
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a nested for loop. Something like this:

```
{% for dat in list_html %}
    <div>
        <span></span>
        <ul>
            {% for d in dat %}
                <li> {{ d }} </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.